# ... and visiting relatives can intrude

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

Could you explain the grammar of this long sentence and the words '**can intrude**' and what part of sentence they relate to.

> They fish together every spring and early summer, the first two or
>   three months of the season, before family vacations, little league
>   baseball, and visiting relatives **can intrude**.

So Much Water So Close to Home
by Raymond Carver

Comment: "can intrude" could easily be in the form "can intrude on their time together". Does that clarify the sentence to you?

Comment: In case the intervening text has caused confusion, the simplified form is "...before... relatives can intrude."